# GraphQL specify array of multiple types

Tags: javascript, graphql, graphql-js

Is there any way to tell GraphQL that a type is an array filled with Strings OR Integers?  Basically this, if it were valid

```
inputHelper: [[String | Int]]
```

So in a query I could validly send over

```
inputHelper: [["foo", 1], ["bar", -1]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could potentially [create a custom scalar](http://dev.apollodata.com/tools/graphql-tools/scalars.html) that could accept either integers or strings.

The easier solution would be to utilize an existing JSON scalar, [like the one here](https://github.com/taion/graphql-type-json). Then you could just do:

```
inputHelper: [JSON]
```

or just

```
inputHelper: JSON
```

Comment: plus 1 - Thanks a ton - looks incredibly promising.  I'll take a closer look tomorrow.